# spacing between tikz nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

The following script

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node(a)[minimum size = 3 cm, draw]
       {top left};
  \node(b)[minimum size = 3 cm, draw] at (a.south)[anchor=north]
       {bottom left};
  \node(c)[minimum size = 3 cm, draw] at (a.east)[anchor=west]
       {top right};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives the output

[image]

How can I add automatic horizontal and vertical spacing between all nodes in a tikz picture?

Comment: you can use `positioning` library

Comment: @percusse Oops, sorry, didn't see your comment before I answered. I can always delete if you want to write up an answer yourself.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. No problem at all. It was just a passing comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common method would be the `positioning` library. By using its `<position> of=<other node>` (see section 17.5.3 *Advanced Placement Options* in the manual for version 3.0.1a) for placing nodes, you can set the default distance with the `node distance` key.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.append style={minimum size = 3 cm, draw},
  node distance=2mm
]
  \node(a) {top left};
  \node(b) [below=of a] {bottom left};
  \node(c) [right=of a] {top right};
\end{tikzpicture}\quad%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.append style={minimum size = 3 cm, draw},
  node distance=-\pgflinewidth
]
  \node(a) {top left};
  \node(b) [below=of a] {bottom left};
  \node(c) [right=of a] {top right};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to specify horizontal and vertical distance?

Comment: @Viesturs Yes, `node distance=2mm and 5mm` will make the vertical distance 2mm and the horizontal distance 5mm.   I do recommend carefully reading the section in the manual I referred to.

Comment: Can I use another `node distance` for a particular node locally?

Comment: @Viesturs Use e.g. `left=2cm of foo`. If you have multiple nodes that should have a node distance, you can use a `scope` environment, `\begin{scope}[node distance=2cm] <nodes go here> \end{scope}`.